# Excel vba pyramid

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm doing some homework and I tried to solve this but have no clue. I would be thankful if somebody would help me.

How to write code for pyramid in excel to look like this:

```
1 
121    
12321    
1234321
```

Comment: Dude, make an effort. Try something. You said it's homework so you must have a class so you must have some idea of what to do.

Comment: For me this looks like a task for understanding how recursion works. Esspecially how the stack works. For understanding recursion you must first understand recursion ;-).

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would use a couple of for loops inside a main loop.

The main loop counter variable would determine what the first inner For loop would count up to and also what the second For loop would count down to one from.

You would just have to convert the loop variables to strings and concatenate them.  Then print them to a cell at the end of the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use cell formula =11^2(i-1) 
Where "i" will be row number and extend it to any number of rows you want

Answer (score 0):

For me this looks like a task for understanding how recursion works. Esspecially how the call stack works.

Since this is a good example and may help others understanding the call stack with recursive functions, I will try to explain:

```
Sub writeNumbersToSheet()
 With ActiveSheet
  For iRow = 1 To 9
   .Cells(iRow, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
   .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = recursive_numbers(1, iRow)
  Next
 End With
End Sub

Sub test()
 s = recursive_numbers(1, 4)
End Sub

Function recursive_numbers(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal j As Integer) As String
 s = s & i
 If i < j Then
  i = i + 1
  s = s & recursive_numbers(i, j) & i - 1
  ' stack 1: i = 2, s = "1"
  ' stack 2: i = 3, s = "2"
  ' stack 3: i = 4, s = "3"
  ' last call recursive_numbers(i, j) = "4"
 End If
 ' get from stack:
 ' s = s & recursive_numbers(i, j) & i - 1
 ' from last call: recursive_numbers(i, j) = "4"
 ' from stack 3: "3" & "4" & 4-1
 ' from stack 2: "2" & "343" & 3-1
 ' from stack 1: "1" & "23432" & 2-1
 recursive_numbers = s
End Function
```

The comments in the `Function` are related to the `Sub test()` which calls a recursion depth of 4. So there are 4 call stack positions, inclusive the last call. The comments explain how they where built up and then break down.